# How do I write log messages in Kohana 3.2?

Tags: kohana, kohana-3

Ok I've tried searching all over but can't seem to get just a simple straight forward answer.

I want to write log messages (`INFO`, `ERROR`, etc.) to the Kohana log file `/application/logs/YYYY/MM/DD.php`.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try the log class `add()` method: http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/api/Log#add

Call it like this:

```
Log::instance()->add(Log::NOTICE, 'My Logged Message Here');
```

For the first parameter (level) use one of the 9 constants defined in the log class

Comment: That worked! Although I also had to add a line to make it write out to the file as well.

`Log::instance()->write();`

Comment: enable log writing when adding to log by specifying Log::$write_on_add=TRUE in your bootstrap file

Answer (score 2):

Shuadoc you shouldn't touch system files (all those under system folder).
Change the value in bootstrap.php instead as stated by Ygam

Otherwise, when updates come you'll be in trouble.